# Detecting nonexistent words with Solr spell checker

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, spell-checking

For simplicity reasons we suppose that our Solr index contains single word: `"test"`.

And our search query is `"test someNonExistentWord"`.

Using Solr's spell checker we will get following result:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
         ...
      }
    ]
  },
  "spellcheck": {
    "suggestions": [
      "correctlySpelled",
      true
    ]
  }
```

So, my question is: How to know that one of word within query is actually doesn't exists?

Sure, straightforward way exists - manual query tokenizing followed by serach for each word separately, but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the **problem could not be solved with built-in spellchecker**.

Fortunately, the Solr is opensource and everyone can modify its code to accomplish this goal.